# Creating WebBrowser Control on Fly and Using Single DocumentComplete event for it

Tags: vb.net, browser

How can I create a webbrowser control and associate a single DocumentComplete event to it ? Basically I want to be able to reuse the same DocumentComplete event but for some reason, it will never stop firing that Event, So when I dispose the webbrowser object, it stopped firing the event. But I want to be able to create another control and reuse that Event for it!

cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Dim web1 As New WebBrowser()
AddHandler web1.DocumentComplete, AddressOf DocumentCompleteEventHandler
' Do stuff
RemoveHandler web1.DocumentComplete, AddressOf DocumentCompleteEventHandler
web1.Dispose()

Dim web2 As New WebBrowser()
AddHandler web2.DocumentComplete, AddressOf DocumentCompleteEventHandler
' Do stuff
RemoveHandler web2.DocumentComplete, AddressOf DocumentCompleteEventHandler
web2.Dispose()
```